# Memory allocation error when trying to create a large zip file in memory

Tags: java, memory, zip, outputstream, zipoutputstream

The memory allocation error specifically seems to occur once it hits the for loop and only for very large storesLists. I only able to hit the memory allocation error if storesList.size() is about 2 million. I've pasted a snipped of the for loop which is supposed to create a new row based off each object in the loop.

The function takes in a ZipOutputStream and a list of objects.

```
 public ZipOutPutStream setStream(ZipoutputStream zos, List<Stores> storesList){
     zos.setLevel(1);
     newRow = new StringBuilder();
      for (Stores s: storesList) {
        //clearing the stringbuilder each iteration
        newRow.setLength(0);
        newRow.append(s.getId());
        newRow.append(",")
            .append(s.getTitle()).append(s.getDescription());
        newRow.append("\n");
      }
      byte[] data = result.toString().getBytes();
      zos.write(data, 0, data.length);
      zos.closeEntry();
      zos.close();
      return zos;
}
```

What should I be changing so that I am able to process very large lists?

Comment: Memory is finite. The real question is why are you creating it in memory in the first place? Why not write it directly to wherever it's going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build a memory structure when you can stream the same data directly - as huge structures may hit `OutOfMemoryError` on the `toString()` or `getBytes()` calls.

If you are dealing with platform line separators you can write out rows like this:

```
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(zos/*,false, orCharSetHere*/);
for (Stores s : storesList) {
    w.println(s.getId() + "," + s.getTitle() + s.getDescription());
}
w.flush();
```

But if you want `\n` line separators for all platforms the rows can be sent using:

```
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(zos/*, orCharSetHere*/);
for (Stores s : storesList) {
    w.write(s.getId() + "," + s.getTitle() + s.getDescription()+"\n");
}
w.flush();
```

The writers must be flushed to ensure any buffered data is written to the `ZipOutputStream` before the zip entry or stream is closed.